# Compute molecular vibrational energy of CO2 molecule using VQE

Tags: qiskit, vqe

I have to compute the molecular vibrational energy of CO2 molecules using VQE, but I am not progressing; Code on the qiskit website does not work. Does anyone have any working code to find vibrational energy of any molecule using qiskit?

code source - [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/nature/tutorials/02_vibrational_structure.html)
Error-

```
    from qiskit_nature.second_q.problems import VibrationalStructureProblem
    from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import DirectMapper
    
    vibrational_problem = driver.run(basis=basis)
    vibrational_problem.hamiltonian.truncation_order = 2
    main_op, aux_ops = vibrational_problem.second_q_ops()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 4
      1 from qiskit_nature.second_q.problems import VibrationalStructureProblem
      2 from qiskit_nature.second_q.mappers import DirectMapper
----> 4 vibrational_problem = driver.run(basis=basis)
      5 vibrational_problem.hamiltonian.truncation_order = 2
      6 main_op, aux_ops = vibrational_problem.second_q_ops()

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_nature/second_q/drivers/gaussiand/gaussian_forces_driver.py:153, in GaussianForcesDriver.run(self, basis)
    150 else:
    151     glr = GaussianLogDriver(jcf=self._jcf).run()
--> 153 watson = glr.get_watson_hamiltonian(normalize=self._normalize)
    155 problem = watson_to_problem(watson, basis=basis)
    156 return problem

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_nature/second_q/drivers/gaussiand/gaussian_log_result.py:287, in GaussianLogResult.get_watson_hamiltonian(self, normalize)
    280     watson = WatsonHamiltonian(
    281         as_coo(quadratic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 2),
    282         as_coo(cubic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 3),
    283         as_coo(quartic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 4),
    284         -as_coo(quadratic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 2),
    285     )
    286 else:
--> 287     quadratic_numpy = np.zeros((max_index,) * 2)
    288     for coord, value in quadratic_data.items():
    289         quadratic_numpy[coord] = value

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Comment: Hello, could you share what you have tried so far? We try to help one another on Stack but are not really a task solving community. Update your question with some attempt, what error you get specifically and some Qiskit knowledgeable person can help you out!

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I should have added the qiskit documentation web page(which has code for this task) and the error I got with that code.